# New android phone retrieve google calendar reminders

Tags: 7.0-nougat, google, google-calendar, samsung-galaxy-s7, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I got a new phone because my old one is destroyed (never to return).

I am trying to get back the reminders I set myself using the google calendar app on my samsung galaxy s7 edge. The reminders would appear in blue on my calendar. I set reminders like, "remind me every 2 weeks to achieve such and such a task, etc., etc."

Anyway, I goto https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r to try and have a look for my reminders and none are there! I can only assume that the reminders were stored in the phone's internal memory because they certainly are not showing in google calendar on a PC... unless I am mistaken about google calendar being a cloud app.

How could @I get my reminders back?

Comment: I'm guessing by 'reminders' you mean 'notifications' attached to Google Calendar appointments. Mine appear ONLY on the website INTENTIONALLY, because I have Google Calendar Notifications OFF on my phone. Do you have this setting, too, albeit unintentionally? See the setting (within Calendar) Settings > Notifications > is ON. You can also get to the setting via Settings > Apps > Calendar > Notifications. Make sure they are not reporting 'Blocked'.

Comment: No, mine say 'alerts'. The point is if you set reminders on a android phone and you lose said phone, the reminders will be lost too. Unless... I'm looking for a solution to this problem. But I did recover my reminders using the PC apps SmartSwitch to backup the phone data and SideSync; which mirrors my destroyed phone screen to a dsktop's monitor. Although getting past the unlock screen with no display was a killer which involved making paper stencil template with keypad numbers. A pain but it did work.